# Using a variable with jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to mix a variable with :not then use that variable with addClass. but no luck yet.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Nav One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

**LESS**

```
ul{
    li{
        a{
            color: black;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            font-size: 3rem;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
}
.enc-non-active{
    color: gray;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
myFunction('ul li a', 'enc-active', 'enc-non-active');

function myFunction($menu, $activeClass, $nonActiveClass) {
   $(function(){
        $($menu).hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass($activeClass);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass($activeClass);
        });
        $($menu).hover(function(){
            var fullPath = $menu + ':not(' + $activeClass + ')';
            $(fullPath).addClass($nonActiveClass);
        },
        function(){
            var fullPath = $menu + ':not(' + $activeClass + ')';
            $(fullPath).removeClass($nonActiveClass);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the CodePen http://codepen.io/antfuentes87/pen/pJEaeb if anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong, that would be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the value of `$menu` and `$activeClass`?

Comment: Whatever the person wanted using the function. For example I would call it like this myFunction('ul li a', 'enc-active', 'enc-non-active'). Did you look at the codepen?

Comment: What function? Please post the code here, not just at CodePen.

Comment: There's no need to use CodePen at all, now that SO has [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0).

Comment: Alright, I will check into the Stack Snippets. For now I just put the code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a dot in :not(.  - easily fixed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGKRyW

```
var fullPath = $menu + ':not(.' + $activeClass + ')';
$(fullPath).addClass($nonActiveClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot to make the class name into a css selector

Change

```
var fullPath = $menu + ':not(' + $activeClass + ')';
```

To

```
var fullPath = $menu + ':not(.' + $activeClass + ')';
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGprVX)**</kbd>